# jQuery easySlider 1.7 - how do I add the next and previous buttons?

Tags: jquery, easyslider

I have the easySlider 1.7 installed on a website that I am working on. For some reason, no matter what I do the next and previous buttons do not show up at all. I am not that new to the whole jQuery thing but I am completely stumped after trying so many different options. I have below my code for the CSS, the jQuery for the slider and my html. Please note I have the slider jQuery in a seperate .js file called, "banner.js" and my CSS is attached to main CSS file. I could really just be overlooking something but I have been looking up and down, all around the web for a solution. Thank you in advance!

CSS:

```
#slider ul, #slider li{ 
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        list-style:none;
        }   
    #slider, #slider li{ 
        height:290px;
        width:1024px;
        overflow:hidden;
        }   
    #slider{ 
        margin-left:0px;
        }   
    #prevBtn, #nextBtn{ 
        width:30px;
        height:77px;
        float:left;
        left:0px;
        top:50px;
        }   
    #nextBtn{ 
        left:1024px;
        }                                                       
    #prevBtn a, #nextBtn a{  
        display:block;
        width:30px;
        height:77px;
        background:url(../images/btn_prev.gif) no-repeat 0 0;   
        }   
    #nextBtn a{ 
        background:url(../images/btn_next.gif) no-repeat 0 0;   
        }

                            `
```

The jQuery Slide Function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#slider").easySlider({
        auto: true, 
        pause:3000,
        continuous: true,
        controlsShow:true,
        prevId:'prevBtn',
        nextId:'nextBtn'

    });
})`
```

The HTML Markup:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="nav">
</div>
<div class="banner">
<div id="slider">
    <ul>
    <li><img src="images/banner/img001.png" alt="001" /></li>

    <li><img src="images/banner/img002.png" alt="002" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/banner/img003.png" alt="003" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="mxNav">
<p class="mxNavText"> Order Now! </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to where i tested your code.  the only difference between what you have and what I have is the images and the file paths to those images.  I would assume at this point that there might be a file path issue.

http://d2burke.com/exp/es_test/

i use this plug in ALL the time and even [extended it's functionality](http://divercityadvertising.com/agency.php).  post a link to your code if you'd like.  i'd be glad to take a look

Comment: Thank you for taking a look! It was definitely a rookie mistake and the path for the images in the CSS weren't right. I got them all working and styled. Thank you again for helping me out!